# Getting exception 'Non-zero amount must be rounded to whole currency' Sage 50 C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, sage50

When I try to add an amount in AmountPaid field & if the amount = 55.23 then it throws an exception with stated text "Non-zero amount must be rounded to whole currency"

I tried `AmountPaid = Match.Ceiling(amount)` which changes the 55.23 to 56 which works great, but I want to make it as it is i.e 55.23
The thing which I understood is that the DB of Sage50 2020 is not allowing amount with decimal places.

```
invoiceLine.AmountPaid = item.amount
```

I think this error is only with .Net SDK which Sage 50 2020 provided to us.
The suggestion will also be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: When no decimals are allowed, than you can't save them. Maybe there's another field where you can store them.

Comment: invoiceLine.Amount= item.amount is also giving me that exception.

Comment: I think you should place a call with sage support. This is going to be specific to their software.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this recently pushing data to Sage 50 (v2022) via the Sage API dlls. We were trying to create an invoice for an item and setting the quantity with decimal values (2 in our case). The item's stocking unit in Sage 50 hadn't been set so it was defaulting to  on the invoice. Sage seems disable use of decimals for quantities on items without a stocking unit set. I understand your question seems related to the extendPrice/Amount, but we were receiving the same error message.

FIX: We had the customer set the stocking unit to LB for that item and we were able to send the invoice with decimal quantities.